# c++ Functions which indicate their return value should be ignored

Tags: c++, return-type

I have a function that returns a value, however under certain conditions (known to the function, but not the caller) I want the caller to ignore the value.

For example, say you want to calculate average ocean temperature. To do so you split the earth into one million parcels and ask each parcel what its temperature is. However when the parcel is on land, the return value needs to indicate that this value shouldn't be included in the average.

I can think of a few ways to make this work but I'm not sure which is a good solution:

1. Define a *fake* value (say -inf) which will never be a sensible
   return value. The caller checks if the value is *fake* before using 
   it.
2. Augment the return type to be a pair where the first part is the
   value and the second a Boolean which indicates *fake-ness*
3. Return a vector which has either one value or no values
4. Throw an exception when the value is to be ignored so the calling
   function can handle the exception and know the value should be
   ignored.
5. Return by pointer and use *nullptr* to indicate that the value
   should be ignored

Solution 1 seems like it would be fastest and easiest to implement, but also most likely to create difficult to find bugs if callers use the function without checking if the value is valid.

Solutions 2 and 3 require a very slightly heavier value to be passed, but seem like a decent approach.

Solution 4 requires throwing an immense number of exception calls as an expected part of the program. I don't have any experience using exceptions like this.

Solution 5 is nice in its generality (and nullptr *feels* like the best way to indicate nothingness) but dereferenceing a pointer just to get a double out seems grossly inefficient.

I know that the only way to **really** know which solution is fastest is to test them all, but I'm wondering if there are any common best practices for handling situations like this.

Performance is relatively important for me as this function is going to get called about 10,000 times per frame.

There are probably answers to questions like this but I don't know what search terms describe this as "c++ fake/ignore return value" are apparently not good ones.

Comment: I would use option 1. It's simple, easily understood by future maintainers, and about as efficient as you're going to get.

Comment: That said, this is an opinion poll question so voting to close.

Comment: Some compilers implement the soon-to-be-standard [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) class. Maybe worth looking at.

Comment: You've put way to much time and effort into this already. 4 is the only really bad option. 1 would be the most common.

Comment: Should I have not supplied any proposed solutions? I was just trying to explain my thinking about the problem so far.

Comment: I would personally avoid 3 & 4 (4 is very bad). 5 would work for me if the pointers were not allocated but raw pointers to pre-existing member variables of the parcels.

Comment: ***Should I have not supplied any proposed solutions?*** I think that part is  fine however the question is an opinion-based which is off topic for SO.

Comment: Solution 6:: Divide the earth into land and water parcels (which already shows, you have a third kind of output (land+water)) and use only relevant parcels in your calculations.

Comment: #2 is `std::optional` (or `boost::optional`)

Comment: Solution 7. instead of using a `std::pair` for the return value, use an output parameter for the value, and return a `bool` if the output is valid.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a somewhat opinion-based question.

My opinion is that the best approach is to return an `optional<T>` object; if it's empty, then it means no value is being returned, and if it's nonempty, then the caller has to explicitly "dereference" it in order to get the value, although no heap allocation or pointers are actually involved. (An exception will be thrown if the caller forgets to check and tries to get a `T` out of an empty `optional<T>`.) You can use `boost::optional` now, or `std::optional` once C++17 comes out.

This is more or less option 2 in terms of performance, but with a better interface.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Answer (score 2):

An easy and cheap way you haven't listed is to pass by reference (output parameter):

```
bool averageValue(int &myVal, ...) {
     // calculate average
     myVal = average;
     if (land) {
         return false;
     }
     return true;
}

int avgVal;
if (averageValue(avgVal, ...)) {
    //add to the total val.
```

This will likely not be as quick as option #1 (but only because of the extra compare) but it will be very very close and has the advantage of code clarity and no magic numbers.

Comment: downvoter, an explanation always leads to a better answer.

Comment: The better answer would be no answer for bad questions.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do #2 (with `boost::optional`, but recent experience has taught me to use option 6 (a variant of 4):

```
bool isValidCoord(int x, int y);
Data getData(int x, int y) {
   assert(isValidCoord(x,y));
   ...
}
```

This splits nicely, and calling code is clean:

```
if(isValidCoord(x, y))
   doCalculation(getData(x,y));
```